# Django CBV : create functions in the same class

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm working on a new project based on `Django Class Based View` and I would like to get advices in order to factorize an important `post function`.

I'm pretty new with this concept.

My post function looks like this :

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        query_document = None
        query_document_updated = None
        query_app = None
        query_document_count = None


    if "UpdateDocument" in request.POST:
        checkbox_id = request.POST['DocumentChoice']
        checkbox_id_minus_1 = int(checkbox_id) - 1

        query_document_updated = Document.objects.get(id=checkbox_id)

        APP_CODE = query_document_updated.app.code
        SRC_FILENAME = query_document_updated.src_filename
        FILENAME, file_extension = os.path.splitext(SRC_FILENAME)
        CATEGORY = query_document_updated.category

        if CATEGORY == "ANNUAL":
            CATEGORY = "ANNUAL_REPORT"

        # Get the new year selected by user
        year = self.request.POST.get('q1year')

        # Create the new document title updated by the new year
        new_document_title = f"{year}_{CATEGORY}_{APP_CODE}" + " - " + f"{SRC_FILENAME}"

        # Create the new document file updated by the new year
        new_document_file = "app_docs/" + f"{APP_CODE}" + "/" + \
                            f"{year}_{CATEGORY}_{APP_CODE}_{checkbox_id_minus_1}{file_extension}"

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'query_app' : query_app,
        'query_document': query_document,
        'query_document_updated': query_document_updated,
        'query_document_count' : query_document_count
    }
    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

I would like to create two new functions : `new_document_title` and `new_document_file` and call both functions in `post`

How I can do that? Create both functions after post and pass variables in arguments ?

Comment: Is there any problem?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Not in my script, but I would like to know How I could rewrite my function `post` in order to cut it to different small functions

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it in a number of ways! I'm writing a few of them here,

### Method-1 : Using `class methods`

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class MyView(APIView):
    def _new_document_title(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something
        return something

    def _new_document_file(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something
        return something

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self._new_document_title()  # calling "_new_document_title"
        self._new_document_file()  # _new_document_file
        # do something
        return some_response
```

### Method-2 : Using `Mixin class`

```
class MyMixin(object):
    def new_document_title(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something
        return something

    def new_document_file(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something
        return something


class MyView(APIView, MyMixin):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.new_document_title()  # calling "new_document_title"
        self.new_document_file()  # new_document_file
        # do something
        return some_response
```

### Method-3 : calling external functions

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView


def new_document_title(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # do something
    return something


def new_document_file(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # do something
    return something


class MyView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        new_document_title()  # calling "new_document_title"
        new_document_file()  # new_document_file
        # do something
        return some_response
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your function in the view class itself(if those are specific to that view) and also in some other mixin(when common to other views too).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class Mixin(object):
    def process(self, data):
        return data


class CBV(APIView, Mixin):

    def utility_function_1(self, data):
        return self.process(data)

    def utility_function_2(self, data):
        return self.process(data)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        processed_data = self.utility_function_1(request.data)
        processed_data = self.utility_function_2(processed_data)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'data': processed_data})
```

Answer (score 1):

The code sample from @umair is the correct direction.

Still, if you want your code to be testable and maintainable at scale, you should outsource your helper functions into another python file:

helpers.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Helper():

    @staticmethod
    def utility_function_1(self, data):
        return process(data)

    @staticmethod
    def utility_function_2(self, data):
        return process(data)
```

views.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# -- adjust -- >import helpers as helper

class CBV(APIView, Mixin):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        processed_data = helper.utility_function_1(request.data)
        processed_data = helper.utility_function_2(processed_data)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'data': processed_data})
```

Comment: would you mind elaborating that If the `utility_function_x` function logic is not re-useable [maybe having some logic very specific to that view] then how will refactoring it to another Helper class help ?

Comment: No one said anything about not re-usable. By exporting it to another file you can more easily write unit tests for your helper-functions.

Comment: :thumbsup: for test-ability